# Как разделить ответ сервера OpenWeatherMap по дням?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Разрабатываю приложение погоды. В процессе работы использую API OpenWeatherMap. С помощью запроса получаю прогноз на 5 дней вперед.[image]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прогноз отдается на 5 дней вперед с интервалом 3 часа (В массиве list как раз 40 элементов).

---

Так вот вопрос в том как мне забирать данные относящиеся к конкретному дню ?  Ведь когда мы, например, запрашиваем прогноз в 00:00, то он отдаётся на 5 дней где каждый день равен 8 элементам. Но если сделать запрос в 12:00 дня, то к текущему дню отдаётся уже не 8 элементов а 4. Надеюсь вы поняли суть моего вопроса.

Comment: Хоть пару элементов массива текстом покажите.

Comment: Исправил вопрос.

Comment: а какой запрос вы делаете? а каким api вы пользуетесь?

Comment: В процессе работы использую API OpenWeatherMap.

Comment: поделитесь ссылкой на описание

Comment: https://openweathermap.org/api

Comment: к какому endpoint вы обращаетесь? с какими аргументами?

Comment: url: '/forecast',
                params: {
                    q: city,
                    appid: API_KEY,
                    lang: 'ru',
                    units:'metric',
                }

Comment: У каждого элемента есть поле dt_txt. Можно преобразовать его в дату. new Date(dt_txt). И дальше уже фильтровать массив с помощью объекта времени, выбирая нужный интервал или число.